# Evaluate: $\sum_{j=1}^{k}\cos(j^{1/k})$

Tags: integration, summation

Where $\lfloor n \rfloor $ is [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)

How to show that if possible?
$$\int_{0}^{1}\lfloor \arccos^k(x)\rfloor \mathrm dx=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\cos(j^{1/k})\tag1$$

and does $\sum_{j=1}^{k}\cos(j^{1/k})$ has a closed form?

Comment: There is a typo in the upper bound of the sum, RHS should be $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\left\lfloor \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^k \right\rfloor} \cos(j^{1/k})$
To derive the formula, treat the integral as a [Riemann–Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral) and integrate by part.